# Why console.log() is called two times instead of one?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've this simple node server:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
  fun();
}).listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');

function fun () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    fun();
    console.log('fun');
  }, 3000);
}

console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:9999');
```

But opening 127.0.0.1:9999 "fun" appears two times each 3 second, instead of just one time. Why?

---

Solved:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(9998, '127.0.0.1');

fun();

function fun() {
        setTimeout(function(){
                fun();
                console.log('fun');
        }, 3000);
}
```

Now "fun" appears one time each three seconds.

Comment: How many http requests has your server handled at the point where `'fun'` starts appearing twice each interval?

Comment: Try logging within the createServer callback function to see how many times that is called

Comment: You might want to look into the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initially call `fun()` from within your http server's callback. That is, each time the http server handles an http request it will call `fun()` again. So after two http requests have been processed there will be two separate fun sequences going and you should see "fun" in the console twice every three seconds. After three requests you should see "fun" in the console three times every three seconds. After *x* requests you should see "fun" *x* times in the console every three seconds.

Comment: I dont think so. For a single request itself, it prints twice.

Comment: @thefourtheye - Oh. Are you sure something isn't causing a double request? I don't think the OP really said whether the URL requested was to a specific page or folder, or just the top level, or...

Comment: I found the actual problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye - Right, OK, that's the sort of thing I meant in that last comment. But wait, how can you be so sure it is definitely the actual problem ("mystery resolved") if you're not the OP? The question doesn't actually say that a browser is used at all...

Comment: OP says `But opening 127.0.0.1:9999` :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're calling the function "fun" every 3 second, it's calling itself inside the setTimeout callback.

Comment: But the question says that "fun" is logged to the console twice every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

### Mystery Resolved.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url);                              //Printing the requested URL
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('ello World\n');
  fun();
}).listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');
```

I printed the URL when a request comes in and it turns out that there are two HTTP requests coming in for every human request. These are the URLs requested.

```
/
/favicon.ico
```

You can read about `favicon` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).  So, both the requests set the timers to 3 seconds. Thats why you see that `fun` getting printed twice.